# Multiline equation: Reduce size and center numbering

Tags: math-mode, equations, labels

The size of this equation is limited by the column (2-column article).

I'm trying to get the equation no. at the center (between both lines), which would mean making the equation smaller. I usually use `\resizebox`. However, it doesn't work and I'm also not able to force a `newline` inside `\resizebox`.

Also, I don't know how much is the behavior of `equation` influenced by using `multline`.

My equation:

```
\begin{multline}\label{eqn:tensionYield}
    f_t(\bs{\sigma},\kappa_t)=\frac{\left( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \right)+\left( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \right)}{2} +\\
    + \sqrt{\left( \frac{\left( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \right)-\left( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \right)}{2} \right)^2 + \alpha \tau_{xy}^2}
\end{multline}
```

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: Off topic: The space before the plus sign at the end of the first line is too narrow.  Add `{}` after this plus to correct the spacing.  (Although it's not usual in U.S. style to "double" the plus; the one on the first line is the one that wouldn't be present.)

Comment: It would be much easier to help if your example started with `\documentclass` and ended with `\end{document}`.  You might also add a sentence (a full line on nonsense words is fine) before the display, and one after it, so that it's easy to determine the actual margins.  Without this necessary context, all attempts to help will be forced to guess, which isn't really effective in providing an accurate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two cases (in the both are used `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` fonts):

- with use of the `nccmath` (for `\medmath` and `\mfrac` commands) and `mathtools` (for `multlined` environment) packages
- with split equation into two parts

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}\medmath{
\begin{multlined}
f_t(\bm{\sigma},\kappa_t) 
    =\mfrac{\bigl( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \bigr){} + 
            \bigl( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \bigr)}{2} + {} \\[1ex]
\sqrt{\left\lgroup \mfrac{\bigl( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \bigr) -
                          \bigl( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \bigr) 
                         }{2} 
     \right\rgroup^2 +
      \alpha \tau_{xy}^2}
\end{multlined}}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
f_t(\bm{\sigma},\kappa_t)
    = A_{(\sigma,\kappa)} + \sqrt{\Bigl(A_{(\sigma,\kappa)}\Bigr)^2 + \alpha \tau_{xy}^2}
\end{equation}
where
\[
A_{(\sigma,\kappa)} = \frac{\bigl( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \bigr) +
           \bigl( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \bigr)}{2}
\]
\lipsum[12-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is always good to insert the complete code when it is possible. There was a command that I have not understood `\bs`. Here there is my proposal after the comments written below. 
Thank you very much to `@barbara beeton` for the precious suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{0.87\hsize}{!}{$\begin{array}{ll}
f_t(\bm{\sigma},\kappa_t) &=\dfrac{\left( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \right)+\left( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \right)}{2}\\[.25cm]
&+ \sqrt{\left( \dfrac{\left( \sigma_x - \sigma_{t,x}(\kappa_t) \right)-\left( \sigma_y - \sigma_{t,y}(\kappa_t) \right)}{2} \right)^2 + \alpha \tau_{xy}^2}\end{array}$}   
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, however splitting the equation and aligning makes it too wide for 1 column. It looks definitely better, but I need to rather shrink the width of equation than extend it. As for the uploading the whole code, I apologize, will do next time - However, the whole article is very long, so I'd rather put this equation separately.

Comment: @JoshE. I have edited the question after your comment. You can see the result.

Comment: There's extra space above the display that shouldn't be there.  However, I'm pretty sure this is a consequence of the `lipsum` entry ending with `\par`.  (A paragraph break before a display *always* messes up the vertical spacing,)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree with you. Can you see, please, if now is more clear and better instead the previous codes? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sadly, the changes you've made are not an improvement.  Better than changing the `\above...` and `\belowdisplayskip` would be to use an option `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}`, that replaces the final `\par` by a space; that would eliminate the excess space between the preceding text and the display.  (There is now too little space there.)  Reducing `\jot` from `3pt` to `1pt` has the effect of placing the denominator "2" in the first line so close to the rule at the top of the root that it's difficult to determine to which line that "2" belongs.  `\jot` shouldn't be changed here.